# Suggested Duplicate list not showing

Tags: bug, flags, duplicate-questions

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999506/php-fatal-error-uncaught-error-class-locale-not-found). I went to look at what suggested duplicates where available but when I clicked on the 'Flag' link no suggestions are displayed:

[image: Missing duplicates]

I can't believe there are no suggested duplicates for this because it has a pretty common title. When I view other questions and click 'Flag' -> 'Duplicate' it shows me suggestions. Just seems to happen on this specific question.

If you type into the field it does find other questions but only once prompted.

---

**Browser**: Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 m

**OS**: Windows 10

Comment: Reproed on Safari 10 / macOS Sierra, so it's not a browser/network issue.

Comment: It's a server issue; the call to http://stackoverflow.com/posts/popup/close/suggest-originals/39999506 does not return a response, while it does for other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/popup/close/suggest-originals/2659035